# Functions of a random variable

Tags: probability-distributions

Assume that $Y$ ~ $Exp(Ω)$. Find the cdf and pdf of $Z$ = |$Y$ - $δ$|.
In order to solve this question so far, for $Y$, I am thinking about using the pdf equation for the exponential distribution i.e. $f(Y)$ = $Ωexp(-Ωx)$ for $x$ > $0$ and $0$ for $x$ < 0. But that is only $Y$, whereas furthermore $Z$ it is shifted by $δ$ to the left and is the absolute value function. Please help me on how to work out the cdf and pdf for this.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is easier to start by the cdf. Let $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

$P(Z\leq z)=P(|Y-\delta |\leq z)=P(\delta - z\leq Y\leq \delta+z)=F_Y(\delta+z)-F_Y(\delta -z)$

where $F_Y(y)=(1-\exp(-\Omega y))\mathbf{1}_{y\geq 0}$ is the cdf of $Y$.

Comment: Can you please also tell how to get the pdf? is it just differentiating the CDF?

Comment: Yes, where it is differentiable.